# ios animation, rotating button, button suddenly changes position

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, rotation

I am trying to implement `animations` in my `application`. I just want to try a simple rotation of a `button`. The button itself is `rotated`, but also it changes its position and the rotation angle is different than the one I want. I have also added the `autoresizesSubwievs = NO;`

```
- (IBAction)rotateView:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
    [self.buttoner setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.buttoner.transform, 90.0f)];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me?

EDIT:
I have two buttons, when the first gets pressed, I call the above method ... but this causes to move the first button and then to move the second button and rotate it with inappropriate angle. I dont understand that at all..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the angle problem, Instead of passing 90, you should pass the radian value of the angle which is **M_PI/2** .

```
[self.buttoner setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.buttoner.transform, M_PI/2)];
```

Comment: Thank you :) Where did it come from? However both of the buttons are still moving when I press the first one :-/ Any ideas why is that so?

Comment: M_PI/2 is the radian value of angle 90. We should give the radians value when rotating.

Comment: I have just noticed that when the button rotates, the first button is moved, but the space between both buttons doesn't change.

Comment: both are still moving ?? really? Is this the only method you have used to animate the button ?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on it. I'll post you the answer in a bit. (only one button is animating)

Comment: Nope nothing more I have just 2 buttons defined as weak nonatomic properties and the one method above.

Comment: hmm .. when the button is rotated, the bottom right corner is still the same. whether it lands in horizontal or vertical position. So it moves that the bottom right corner does't change its position ..